# I am struggling with with natural language process that gives me list index out of range error

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I am running the web crawling to gather the comments from website with selenium chrome. But I am having

> IndexError: list index out of range with code driver from this code

```
find_elements_by_class_name("item")[i].click()
```

the full codes are :

```
for i in range(0,len(item_number)):

driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item")[i].click() <gives error>

time.sleep(2.5)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-tab-id='review']").click()
time.sleep(1.5)
if driver.find_elements_by_class_name("review_tit")[1].find_element_by_class_name("count").text =='총 0개':
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
else:
    review_number = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("review_txt"))
    if review_number== 20:
        while review_number == 20:
            review_number = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("review_txt"))
            for j in range(review_number):
                review.append(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("review_txt")[j].text)
                score.append(int(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//i[@class="star"]')[j+1].get_attribute("style").split(" ")[1].split("%")[0])/20)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(1.5)
            element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('next_page')[0]
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
            time.sleep(1.5)
            review_number=len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("review_txt"))
        else:
            for j in range(review_number):
                review.append(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("review_txt")[j].text)
                date.append(driver.find_element_by_id("_reviewList").find_elements_by_class_name("date")[j].text)
                score.append(int(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//i[@class="star"]')[j+1].get_attribute("style").split(" ")[1].split("%")[0])/20)
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

---

the error is

> IndexError: list index out of range

from this code

```
---> driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item")[i].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name) that method returns an empty list if nothing is found. An empty list would break the `[i]` list access. Are you sure you are getting something back? Split the line into two and try

```
result = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item")
if( len(result) > 0):
    result[i].click()
```

If this works, you might consider using try catch blocks to gracefully exit the program when such errors occur.